# Xlsxwriter scaling images with no scale input

Tags: python, image, xlsxwriter

It seems that either xlsxwriter or excel itself is scaling the image I am inserting into excel. This is an issue for me because I would like to align a second image right below the first image using 'y_offset'. 
Here is my code:

```
file_name = 'Output File.xlsx'
img1 = Image.open('Image1.png')
imgwidth1, imgheight1 = img1.size


workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(file_name)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Summary')

worksheet.insert_image('A1', 'Image1.png')
worksheet.insert_image('A1', 'Image2.png',{'y_offset':imgheight1})
workbook.close()
```

When I look at the output file the first image is in A1 but the next image has about 30 blank rows between it and the first image. I kinda did a rough check of how much it was scaled down and its about 1/3 the size it should be. If it helps both images DPI is at 300. I'm just wondering if this is excel or is it xlsxwriter and how I can fix it so that both images are aligned with each other and there is not space between them.

Comment: I fixed the issue by switching the file type from png to jpeg.

Comment: It is almost certainly an Excel issue since that is how Excel behaves when you insert images. Particularly if the have a high DPI since the default is taken as 96 DPI and images are scaled up or down when displayed in Excel accordingly. (In your case 96/300 = ~1/3 which you are seeing.) XlsxWriter just replicates/implements Excel's image handling.